# Why is my onTouchListener called for neighbour views?

Tags: java, android, events, touch

In my application I want to add a simple animation to buttons and other views acting as buttons.

To do this I set a custom onTouchListener to all views and call startAnimation on them.

My onTouch method looks like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // Only show animation when enabled.
    if (v.isEnabled()) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            v.startAnimation(shrink);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.startAnimation(grow);
            break;
        }
    }
    return v.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This works ok as the views are resized to a smaller size while the user presses the button and returns to the original size when the user releases the finger.

However for some reason other buttons that lie near the touched button also get the UP event so they get a small animation flicker as well.

Why is this, and more importantly, how do I prevent this annoying behaviour?

Edit: Just to be clear. The neighbour views are also registered to the same listener instance, but they are not touched by my finger.

Comment: It might be worth adding a logging statement to this method, printing the view id.  Also print a couple candidate view ids in the activity's onCreate method. What you'll see probably isn't a surprise, but it will at least verify that this event is firing for both the expected view and the "neighbour" view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using the same Animation instance on several views. Creating seperate instances for each view fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The view to wich you have registered listener then should only get notified then also use following approach.

You can explicitly check what is id of View and then only start animation.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.desired_view_id) {
        // Only show animation when enabled.
        if (v.isEnabled()) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.startAnimation(shrink);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.startAnimation(grow);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return v.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: The other views are also registered to the same listener. However this happens even when I don't touch them.

Comment: Exactly!! the method you wrote will be applicable to all views that why you need to check by id which view called this method..use snippt i have posted above.